# undefined is not an object (evualating 'console.warn(this.state.user_id).catch')

Tags: react-native, state

I want to see user id in state. I got an error like this when I ran console.warn in xx function. User id get to in local storage.but is not working for me. run on android emulator. pls help me, what is wrong ? what is wrong ? what is wrong ? what is wrong ? what is wrong ? what is wrong ? what is wrong ?

```
 goLogin() {
    let formdata = new FormData();

    storage.load({key: 'loginState'}).then(ret => {
      this.setState({
        user_id : ret.userid
      })
    })


    console.warn(state.user_id)



    .catch(err => {
      console.warn(err.message);
    });
    if(this.state.isChecked30 == true){
      this.setState({
        expiration: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 30))
      })
    }
    else if(this.state.isChecked60 == true){
      this.setState({
        expiration: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 60))
      })
    }
    else if(this.state.isChecked90 == true){
      this.setState({
        expiration: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 90))
      })
    }

    formdata.append("product[name]", this.state.name)
    formdata.append("product[category_id]", this.state.category_id)
    formdata.append("product[body]", this.state.body)
    formdata.append("product[currency]", this.state.currency)
    formdata.append("product[is_active]", this.state.is_active)
    formdata.append("product[default_value_id]", this.state.default_value_id)
    formdata.append("product[status]", this.state.status)
    formdata.append("product[neighborhood_id]", this.state.neighborhood_id)
    formdata.append("product[view]", this.state.view)
    formdata.append("product[user_id]", this.state.user_id)
    formdata.append("product[expiration]", this.state.expiration)
    formdata.append("product[shipping]", this.state.shipping)
    formdata.append("product[shipping_price]", this.state.shipping_price)
    //formdata.append("")
    this.state.document.forEach((item, i) => {
      //console.warn(item);
      formdata.append("product[image_attributes][file][]", {
        uri: item,
        type: "image/jpeg",
        name: item.filename || `filename${i}.jpg`,
      });
      //console.warn(formdata)
    });

    console.warn(formdata);
    var url = 'xxxx';
    var response = {}
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
      body: formdata, // data can be `string` or {object}!
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.warn(responseJson)

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `console.warn(state.user_id)` in between `.then` and `.catch`. Do this your code will run.

```
storage.load({key: 'loginState'}).then(ret => {
      this.setState({
        user_id : ret.userid
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.warn(err.message);
    });
```